# Display Charts and Graphs in MS Teams using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am currently working on a bot built using MS Bot Framework and Ii'm looking for a solution to display charts (i.e. pie charts, etc.) inside MS Teams using Bot Framework. The goal is to get data from a SQL database, process it to form a chart and send it as an attachment or adaptive card to MS Teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague - I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for *exactly*, but maybe this can help: I can think of 3 possible ways to do this:

1) Generate your graph programmatically, e.g. in C# (there are a bunch of possibly libraries for this), save it to a temporary location (e.g. Azure blob storage) and then embed the link as a message from the bot

2) same as above, but insert it into an adaptive card (not required, but maybe if you want to send other things like text message etc.

3) Create a [Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs) to go along with your bot, which is basically a web page you host somewhere, that shows the graph using, for example, a javascript library. The tab appears along the top in the bot's conversation with the user, and you can have an adaptive card with a button that deep links to the tab, for instance.

Which approach you choose might depend on the size of the chart, whether it needs to be interactive, and I'm sure other possible factors. There are also other possible ways to tackle this I'm sure, but these are hopefully some good ideas/starting points.

Comment: by the way, where is your SQL  Database hosted, and how will the bot access it's data?

Comment: Thank You, Hilton, for the answer. The database used is a MySQL database hosted on an on-premises server. Can you suggest some C# libraries to create graphs effectively?

Comment: No, I can't help with that unfortunately - the last time  I looked at it was a -long- time ago :-(. Glad to have helped overall though - please upvote or mark as answer if you feel the answer was worthwhile.

Comment: This might another possible approach - Excel Services I think used to do something  like this - not sure if it's still a relevant technology. If you just want a pie chart, then mermaid might even be able to help somehow: https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/pie

Comment: Ok. Thank you Hilton, I will look into it. Also, I found   System.Window.Form.DataVisualization Library to create charts and save them to png.

Comment: Ok. Not sure that will work well on a hosted environment, but also worth a try. Keep me posted, would love to know what you end up using